# Words re breaking at the end of line on textview

Tags: android, layout

I am developing an android application that needs to show some description about application, for this i had used a Text view and set all text to it but the problem is that some word are breaking at end of paragraph. I had set all possible properties to Text view but i am not able to find out any solution. Please anybody help me, i got stuck into it. Thanks in advance.

Here is the image  as mentioned above[image]

As the words are breaking at the end of lines. please provide any help or link.

Comment: add layout:gravity="left" property in your XML, for the textview.

Comment: Can you try this with a different typeface? This is not happening to me. If that doesn't solve your problem please share your code and layout so I can check it on my computer. Because this is not the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me when setting some custom type font to the textview. When removing or changing the custom type font worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the ellipsize property you're looking for [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)

Comment: it will make .... at the end but i do not want to do in that way. i want complete word at end of sentence

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your text is too long for the screen. Add a scrollview, add a linearlayout inside and a textview inside that linearlayout. Add your button to that linearlayout too and whole screen will scroll.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. You can also see from the screenshot that it is already inside a scrollview.